# Atmel SAM E70 SPI Chip-Select (SPCS) lines

Tags: spi, atmel

I deliberate the datasheet of Atmel's SAM E70 Cortex-M7 and i have a confusion about SPI.
When SPI is in master mode, it uses NPCS lines for Chip Select (Slave Select). But i can't find a report which explain that those lines used all of them (as outputs) by the peripheral, or there's able to using one of them.
Therefore, it is forced by hardware to make all SPCS lines as outputs in master mode? Or it is possibility to get only one SPCS line, as chip-select, only SPCS0 for example?

By the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11296-32-bit-Cortex-M7-Microcontroller-SAM-E70Q-SAM-E70N-SAM-E70J_Datasheet.pdf):

The SPI operates in Master mode or in Slave mode. The SPI operates in Master mode by writing a 1 to the MSTR bit in the SPI Mode Register (SPI_MR).

- **Pins NPCS0 to NPCS3 are all configured as outputs.**
- The SPCK pin is driven.
- The MISO line is wired on the receiver input.
- The MOSI line is driven as an output by the transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

Being an output or an input has nothing to do with what your lines will do if they are configured as Chip selects.

You may either configure them as GPIOs (in which case they have nothing to do with the SPI subsystem) or as SPCS lines (in which case the GPIO configuration becomes irrelevant). Of course you are able to only configure 1 or 2 or 3 chip selects and the other line(s) as GPIOs (inputs or outputs).

Comment: But according to the datasheet, when SPI works on Master mode, NPCSlines are configured all as outputs.
And im considering that if working SPI in Master mode, i will not able to use only one NPCSline as chip-select.

Comment: You say that i'm able to use only one NPCS line as chip select and the others for, other special function such as GPIO. Right? And why in the datasheet refers: "Pins NPCS0 to NPCS3 are all configured as outputs.", in the master mode description?

Comment: If you look at the datasheet, p.319 (the graphic) and chapter 30.5.2 you will see that you choose a peripheral function but that is always overriden by the PIO-PE/DR registers (which is basically what tells the pin if it's a GPIO or something else). Sure, the SPI block will drive the signal but the pin will never "see" that signal.

Comment: I would think that the "all" related to SPI master/slave mode. In slave mode you will always have only one chip select (NPCS0) and in master mode you can have all 4.

Comment: I haven't worked with the E70 family but with the SAM3, SAM4, UC3, ... and it's always like that.

Comment: From this datasheet? http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11296-32-bit-Cortex-M7-Microcontroller-SAM-E70Q-SAM-E70N-SAM-E70J_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: I know that i can have all 4 NPCS lines as output in Master mode, but i'm searching to learn if i'm able to using less than 4 lines, one or two NPCS lines it is enough for me.

Comment: Therefore, the refer in the datasheet "Pins NPCS0 to NPCS3 are all configured as outputs." says that NPCSx lines, in Master mode, it is being ONLY outputs OR something else? I was confuded by the term of "**all** outputs".

Comment: In the slave mode, there's a reference which says "NPCS1 to NPCS3 are not driven and **can be used for other purposes.**" In the Master mode there's no relative reference where it explain that there is an ability of using less than 4 NPCS lines as chip select, and an ability of using other lines as General Purpose Inputs, or General Purpose Outputs.

Comment: As stated before, look at the I/O Control logic. Only the function you select becomes active. The SPI block has no chance of forcing the pin to be in its SPI function. If it is, and the PIO controller has been setup to perform that function, it will drive the output pin. As soon as you configure the PIO controller differently, the SPI will still try to drive the pin but the MUX of the GPIO Controller will simply select another function. This holds true for every component. I know that for tiny controllers (atmega), setting a bit in e.g. the timer will override the pin function - not here.

Comment: I remember that, in AVR, specifically, in ATMEGA32 SPI, didn't work if it's not set the coresponding CS as output.

Comment: You're missing the point. Ultimately it's NOT the SPI peripheral that's driving the pin but the PIO controller. The Atmega32 doesn't even have the concept of such an advanced PIO controller. The PIO controller is a fully fledged peripheral between the SPI IP and the Pin.

Comment: As i understanding, when i have SPI enabled, NPCS lines (NPCS0 to NPCS3) are forced configured as outputs only, until i choosing to give permit to PIO Controller and geting a pin as i defined (input or output).

Comment: Each NPCS line is routed internally to the PIO controller. The PIO controller decides which function the Pin will actually execute (see the graphic on p.319 where it says Peripheral A Output Enable, Peripheral B output enable, ...). Each pin on that controller can have up to 5 different functions (plus be a normal GPIO pin). Also, think about it: Why is the same NPCS line routed to multiple output pins if all of them were active at the same time?

Comment: Chapter 40.6.1:The pins used for interfacing the compliant external devices can be multiplexed with PIO lines. The programmer must first program the PIO controllers to assign the SPI pins to their peripheral functions.

Comment: i get it, sorry for all that questions, but i want to be sure. With a power of PIO Controller, it's able to using a irelevant pin as Chip Select, if programmer wants that. right? I asking that because i'm thinking that it isn't easy to using NPCS0 as chip select for my application and im forced to using something else, NPCS1 or NPCS2 perhaps.

Comment: It's not irrelevant which pin you use (you can only use such pins which have an Alternate function of NPCS). Yet, there is no need to use them, they will not by themselves override the PIO controller. The PIO controller is the peripheral in charge of all Pin.